# Python prevent readline from converting to hex value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using readline command and getting hex values. However when I print the data received it converts few of the hex values to characters.
Example:

```
b'\x06\x02ABL\x00\x00\x00\x02'
#         ^^^
```

I would like it to be displayed as

```
b'\x06\x02\x41\x42\x4C\x00\x00\x00\x02'
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you share your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898730/python-readline see if it helps

Comment: I tried with data \x06\x02\x41\x42\x4C\x00\x00\x00\x02 and used code with open("D:\\Test.txt", 'r') as f: print f.readline() it returned me correct result i-e \x06\x02\x41\x42\x4C\x00\x00\x00\x02

Comment: Please avoid using code in comments, edit your answer instead

Comment: I am using a terminal which sends byte that content hex data. I am reading using serial readline command and the when I do that , this is what I get: b'\x06\x02ABL\x00\x00\x00\x02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the representation of a bytestring in Python e.g.:

```
>>> b'\x30\x31\x00'
b'01\x00'
```

It shows printable bytes as their ascii symbols instead of the corresponding hex escapes.

> I am using readline command and getting hex values.

*"hex values"* is just a sequence of bytes (numbers in range 0 to 255) here.

If you want to display all bytes as the corresponding hex values:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'01\x00')
b'303100'
```